# How do I make a submit button work with this form?

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

```js
//submit button
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

       var firstNameInput = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastNameInput = $("#lastName").val();
        var pointsEarnedInput = $("#pointsEarned").val();
        var pointsPossibleInput = $("#pointsPossible").val();

    var num1 = $("#pointsEarned").val(),
        num2 = $("#pointsPossible").val(),
        result = parseInt(num1, 10) / parseInt(num2, 10);
        $(".result").submit.

    $("#first").html(firstNameInput);
    $("#last").html(lastNameInput);
    $("#pointsE").html(pointsEarnedInput);
    $("#pointsPoss").html(pointsPossibleInput);

});

//student object
var Student = {
    firstName : $("#firstName").val(),
    lastName : $("#lastName").val(),
    percentage : $("#pointsEarned / #pointsPoss").val(),
    letterGrade : $("#").val(),
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="first"></h1>
<h2 id="last"></h2>
<h3 id="pointsE"></h3>
<h4 id="pointsPoss"></h4>

<form id="myForm">
    <p><input id="firstName" type="text">first name</p>
    <p><input id="lastName" type="text">last name</p>
    <p><input id="pointsEarned" type="text">points earned</p>
    <p><input id="pointsPossible" type="text">points possible</p>

    <p><input type="submit"></p>


</form>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my first time programming, and was wondering how I would type this out in html and javascript/jquery?

Create a form for entering student data. It should contain the following fields:

-first name
-last name
-points earned
-points possible

When the submit button is pressed, create a student object. Using the object, output the following:

-first name
-last name
-percentage
-letter grade

Comment: Do you plan to submit the form or do anything with the form data? Or do you just want to show it on a page? In other words, what are you going to do with this student object?

Comment: the form data just needs to output somewhere on the screen, I guess above or below the form is good enough. j08691, this isn't homework / it's not worth anything. I just posted what code I have. Its incomplete and not sure if it's on the right track